# Return only line number, if pattern 'Exist' and 'Not Exist'. using 'grep' command

Tags: grep

I have this sample file for my input:

```
xyxxyx xyxx xxyx yxyy yxyx
xxyxxx xx xyx xxx x y x xxyy
yxxy xyxxy xxy y x y
xyxy xyx yyxx xyyxyxy xyx
yxyy xyy yxyx xxyxyyx
```

And I tried to find only `"xyx"` word if exist in line and return line number. for example in this input just line 2 and 4 have `"xyx"`, and the result I desired is only would be 2 and 4 (line numbers) but `grep` command give me all 5 lines. this result:

```
grep -n "xyx" test | cut -f1 -d:
1
2
3
4
5
```

If I run follow command without `cut -f1 -d"` I see that find all `"xyx"` such as in `"xyxxyx"`, `"xyxx"`, `"xxyx"` and `"yxyx"` for example in first line, while that is wrong, my pattern only and only exist in line 2 and 4 and it is third word in line 2 and second & 5th word in line 4. See the screen shot:

[image]

And the result what I want is, only find separated `"xyx"` and return line number of that.

output of I desired if pattern exist, it is just:

```
2
4
```

output of I desired if pattern not exist, it is just:

```
1
3
5
```

and also I don't know which command I should use to check if pattern not exist. I tried with all possible combination of `grep` command but I failed.

Thank you for helping in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `-w` option

```
$ grep -wn 'xyx' file | cut -d: -f1
2
4
```

From `man grep`

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
```

To invert the match, add the `-v` switch i.e.

```
grep -vwn 'xyx' file | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: I have added it